# What is the correct usage of -rpath in manifest.xml?

Tags: ros, manifest.xml, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently came across this error when running `roswtf` to try and diagnose the cause of a weird intermittent failure:

`ERROR The following packages have rpath issues in manifest.xml: * flyer_controller: found flag "-L/home/bouffard/ros/starmac-ros-pkg/starmac_flyer/flyer_controller/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/home/bouffard/ros/starmac-ros-pkg/starmac_flyer/flyer_controller/lib"`

The manifest actually has this (note the `-L` after the `rpath`):

```
  <export>
    <nodelet plugin="${prefix}/flyer_controller_nodelets.xml"/>
    <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include" 
         lflags="-L${prefix}/lib -Wl,-rpath,-L${prefix}/lib -lros"/>
  </export>
```

.. and the package (and others which depend on it and use the library) does build and seems to work.

If I remove that `-L` then the `roswtf` error goes away. However according to the example on the  [Manifest/XML wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Manifest/XML#export_cpp) the `-L` *should* be present; I don't actually know what all these flags do but the `-L` just seems out of place there to me. My guess is that the wiki page is incorrect, but I don't quite see how I never had build problems with the wrong syntax.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10246/what-is-the-correct-usage-of--rpath-in-manifest.xml?/) by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2264 on 2011-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Manifest/XML) was incorrect.  I just fixed it.  You shouldn't supply the `-L` prefix when specifying a `-rpath` directory to the linker.

To parse out the incantation: `-Wl,foo,bar,bat,bang` tells the compiler to pass to the linker `foo`, `bar`, `bat`, and `bang`, in that order, as space-separated arguments.  So when you say `-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/my/lib`, the linker will get `-rpath /path/to/my/lib`.  And in that context, the linker doesn't want the `-L` prefix on the directory (not sure whether it would behave properly or not).

And in case you're curious, the whole `rpath` business is needed to allow ROS executables to depend on shared libraries that are sprinkled all throughout the package tree.  Otherwise you'd have to put all the directories containing libraries in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.    With the forthcoming `rosbuild2`, we'll be moving away from explicit use of `rpath` arguments, and toward a more conventional way of organizing libraries (including allowing them to be installed into a common location).

Thanks for the report.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-06-13**:
Thanks. Still puzzled why anything ever worked with that error in there, but I'm also content to leave it a mystery.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2018-01-11**:
I love the ROS wiki... your wiki link links to an empty wiki page with a link to another documentation page... which now 404s. Awesome, folks!